# Calling VBA-Macros with user-defined Types from C#?

Tags: c#, automation, ms-word

I've got a Word Document with a VBA Module that contains user defined Types (public Type XXX) and some public subs that take this Type as arguments. Is it possible to call these subs from C# via Application's Run()?

Greetings,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have the flexibility to do this, but here's how I solved this.

1. Create another assembly (I called mine "xx.Common")
2. Add some structs in there, make them COM-visible
3. Reference that assembly from both the VBA and C# projects
4. Add a new VBA sub with those structs as arguments

You can now pass in structured, user-defined data. If you generalize this idea, you can use *any* COM-visible type (i.e. not just structs). As long as both projects reference an assembly that defines these types, you should be ok.